# Trouble comparing strings in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the field `date` in my MySQL DB as a string, and I want to compare it to another string in a MySQL query to get the recent activity for a user within a week. But for some reason I am getting no returned data from the fetch_assocs.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$week = uk_date();
    echo $week . " - ---------- -";
    $week = $week - (60*24*7);
    echo $week;
    $array = array();
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE `date` > " . $week . "") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$q) {}
    if (mysql_num_rows($q) < 1) {

    }
    else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $array['posts'][] = $row;
        }
    }
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE `date` > " . $week . "") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($q) < 1) {

    }
    else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $array['comments'][] = $row;
        }
    }
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE `date` > " . $week . "") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($q) < 1) {

    }
    else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $array['likes'][] = $row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We really can't say, because you're not showing any meaningful data. What kinds of values does `date` contain, and what does `$week` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have the field date in my MySQL DB as a string,"... your date field is a char/varchar/text? That means you will NOT be able to do direct date/time calculations, because you're not using date/time values. If you're storing dates in a field, then make that field a date or datetime type.

Then you can do stuff like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE `datefield` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: I don't like it because this query won't be added to mysql cache.

Answer (score 0):

Don't calculate the week in PHP at all - that's something the database can do, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE date > date_sub(CUR_DATE(), interval 7 day);
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff to learn about the magic of MySQL Date operations.

Comment: I don't like it because this query won't be added to mysql cache.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of simple date try to use STR_TO_DATE(`date`) in mysql query and for week try to use 
php function strtotime("-1 week");

Comment: Using functions on table fields in a where clause prevents the use of indexes, as you're comparing derived values. Also non-cacheable, to throw your argument back in your face.

Comment: @Marc-B I don't know format of the date and it's necessary to check maybe it will work without STR_TO_DATE. But could you give me a link about non-cacheable with STR_TO_DATE? It seems that you are wrong.

Comment: as soon as you give me a link that says using date_sub is non-cacheable.

Comment: @Marc-B It uses CUR_DATE() or now(). This is non-cacheable. Next time before downvoted look through manual.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. FYI: I only downvote things that obviously wrong. Merely having a different opinion on how to do something is not wrong. Downvoting for a difference of opinion is pathetically childish and better suited for places like reddit.

Comment: @Marc-B Maybe I don't know but your phrase 'Also non-cacheable, to throw your argument back in your face.' is a cause. Someone else doesn't know how mysql query cache works.